# ImportError: cannot import name 'TextArea' from 'CWH' in TextArea

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try to make text area to my gui i got this error i have created same variable to other file which name is CWH.py

```
from tkinter import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1200x500")
    root.title("Untitled - Notepad")
    root.wm_iconbitmap("icon.ico")
    TextArea = Text(root, font = "Arial 13")
    file = None
    TextArea.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)






root.mainloop()
```

Error:- ImportError: cannot import name 'TextArea' from 'CWH'

Relevent Lines in CWH.py File:-

```
TextArea = Text(root, font="lucida 13")
file = None
TextArea.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
```

Comment: where is the import statement in your code?

Comment: What i have to import??

Comment: No...CWH is python file not a module

Comment: The error is showing an ImportError where is the line of the import which causes the error in your provided code?

Comment: Show the entire error code and also the relevant lines in CWH file

Comment: Done, Check Now

Comment: You need to learn what `if __name__ == '__main__'` does. Your `TextArea` is undefined as long as you don't run CWH.py independently. You prolly need to remove `if` entirely.

Comment: Note that the code inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block will not be executed if the file is imported from other file.